# Moving /tmp folder to different location. Problems with /tmp not being emptied

Tags: ssd, tmp

I have two harddrives on my computer running Linux Mint. The first is an SSD and has my `/` partition and the second is an HDD and has my `/home` partition.

I have heard that too many writes to the SSD is bad, so I have attempted to move the location of the `/tmp` folder to somewhere on the HDD. To do this I created a folder on that drive, gave owner to root, set permissions via `chmod` to `1777`, then ran

```
ln -s /tmp /new/location/tmp
```

Applications seem to be using the new `/tmp` folder, but the folder does not seem to be emptying itself on reboot. I have edited `/etc/default/rcS` to set `TMPTIME=0`, but this does not seem to fix the issue.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I never tried doing this with `/tmp`, but I did this with `/var/{tmp,log,cache}`.  Can you try using bind mounts instead? i.e. edit `/etc/fstab`, add `/HDD/tmp /tmp none bind 0 0`, remove the original `/tmp` symlink, recreate the directory, then reboot.

Comment: Some distros default to `/tmp` on tmpfs, so it's not backed by disk at all (other than swap space).  I'd suggest that if you don't want `/tmp` churn on your SSD.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, good point. I had a search to see what it was in Mint, but I found some clear instructions for `/tmp` [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1366).

Comment: There is no use in putting `/tmp` onto a harddisk, unless you are running some very specific applications. Otherwise, the amount of writes is **really** negligible, and you will almost certainly change your SSD due to its insufficient size earlier than it will approach even 50% of its write cycles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `ln -s /tmp /new/location/tmp`

The command is backwards. The parameter order for `ln` is the same as for `mv` or `cp`: source, then destination.

You might want to consider [resizing your `/home` partition](http://gparted.org/articles.php) to make space for a new `/tmp` partition, since it needs to be available very early in the boot process, possibly before `/home` comes up.

Alternately, you can [mount `/tmp` as a ramdisk](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/overview-of-ramfs-and-tmpfs-on-linux/), if your system isn't tight on RAM.

Comment: How much RAM should I have to mount /tmp as a ramdisk? Even if I have enough is that preferable? Thanks

Comment: @user45150: Re: How much RAM, obviously you need to be able to dedicate as much free RAM as your system ever needs for `/tmp` space. There is no way I can tell you how much that is. It's like asking how much space you need for MP3s.

Comment: @user45150: Re: Whether it's preferable, I'd argue "no," because your OS's [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) keeps much of `/tmp` in RAM already. `/tmp` on a RAM disk was more common before buffer caching systems became as sophisticated as they are today. I offered the idea only because it would be a way to move `/tmp` off the SSD without making space for a dedicated partition on the HDD. It's not a bad solution, just not as efficient as making use of the OS's page cache, since the OS knows better than you do what it needs at any given instant.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to create a new partition for /tmp on the new hard disk.

And then add it to /etc/fstab

```
UUID="uuid-of-new-partition" /tmp ext4 Defaults 0 0
```